# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts in WPF

Tags: c#, exception, database-connection, mysql.data

I can't figure out what's wrong with the connection string. I tried all possible variations of the string. It's done in a WPF framework in vs 2015. I just installed SQL server 2016 newly.

The code is:

```
string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=EliseDB;Uid=root;Pwd=";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

The error shown is:

> **'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll**
>
> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional Information:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

I even tried restarting TCP/IP in server config manager.

Comment: *I just installed SQL server 2016* ... well that is awesome but that isn't going to help if your code tries to connect to a MySql database ... try using the SqlConnection class instead or install MySql server,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like the following:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost, 3306;
Initial Catalog=EliseDB;User ID=root"

SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)

try
{
    cnn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Opened connection!");
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Big Problem: " + ex.message);
}
```